I am trying to make a lego controller using pybricks, pybricksdev, and pyautogui for simulating keypresses in a virtual environment
The error is it shows no module found
ImportError: no module named 'pyautogui'
from pybricks.hubs import PrimeHub
from pybricks.pupdevices import ForceSensor, ColorSensor
from pybricks.parameters import Port, Color
from pybricks.tools import wait
import pyautogui as pg
# from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
# keyboard = Controller()





hub = PrimeHub()
force_sensor = ForceSensor(Port.A)
color_sensor = ColorSensor(Port.B)


def check_color_movement():
    detected_color = color_sensor.color() 
    
    if detected_color == Color.GREEN:
        return "1"
    elif detected_color == Color.BLUE:
        return "11"
    else:
        return "0"

while True:
    output = ""
    output1 = ""


    if force_sensor.pressed():
        output1 += "111"


    movement = check_color_movement()
    if movement != "0":
        output += movement


    if output == '1':
        print("left") 
        pg.press('a')
        # keyboard.press('a')
        # keyboard.release('a')  
    elif output == '11':
        print("right")
        # pg.press('d')
        # keyboard.press('d')
        # keyboard.release('d')
    if output1:
        print("shoot")
        # pg.press('space')
        # keyboard.press('space')
        # keyboard.release('space')   

    wait(100)

Files
this is what i tried in a virtualo environment
and the launch.json file has this code for pybricksdev
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
"name": "Python Debugger: Module",
"type": "debugpy",
"request": "launch",
"module": "pybricksdev",
"args": ["run", "ble", "${file}"],
}
]
}

Maybe your installation of pyautogui wasn't successfull, try again using this

iI tried installing again but same error in the virtual environment if i disable pybricksdev and pybricks pyautogui works perfectly but once i uncomment the launch.json file and pybricks import and everything else related to pybricks and pybricks dev it again shows the error
